# Who are 'Friend of Big Toad' and 'Lady Astronaut'?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

They are listed in The Force Awakens credits.

Answer (score 6):

'*Lady Astronaut*' (played by [Sandy Kate Slade](https://star-wars-canon.fandom.com/wiki/Sandy_Kate_Slade)) appears in the cantina scene.

[image]

She walks behind Rey just as she's entering the catacombs.

[image]

---

'*Friend of Big Toad*' was portrayed by Second Unit Director [Clare Glass](https://twitter.com/JoonasSuotamo/status/1258107008475189248/photo/1).

I believe this is her, hanging around with a guy that I can only assume was originally dubbed "Big Toad"

[image]